# Функция mail в php.Проблема с передачей данных

Tags: forms, email, php, html

Вот код:
**HTML** КОД
http://jsfiddle.net/9om00gw5/

PHP код

```
<?php

$result = mail ("test@test.ru","Анкета Сайта","С сайта была получена анкета с такими данными: Имя: $S_POST[name] Пароль: $S_POST[password], Любите ли экономить время: $S_POST[time], Сколько часов в день спит: $S_POST[sleep] часов Свои нароботки в экономии времени $S_POST[text]");

if ($result) {
echo "<p>Сообщение отправлено успешно!</p>";
}
else {
echo "<p>Сообщение не отправлено</p>";
}

?>
```

**РЕЗУЛЬТАТ**

> X-Sendmail-Cmdline: sendmail.pl -t -i
> To: test@test.ru
> Subject: Анкета Сайта
> X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:formdata.php
> С сайта была получена анкета с такими данными: Имя:  Пароль: , Любите ли экономить время: , Сколько часов в день спит:  часов Свои нароботки в экономии времени

Данные не передаются.Что не так ?

Comment: `$_POST`, а не `$S_POST`?

Comment: блин...) спс+